# Is there a way in SQL to order by lowest to high and then 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sorting

I have a question about SQL.
Imagine you have some items in your table like this:

```
1 => id:1, title: Hey, order: 1
2 => id:2, title: Second, order: 3
3 => id:3, title: Third, order: 6
4 => id:4, title: Forth, order: 2
5 => id:5, title: Fifth, order: 0
6 => id:6, title: Sixth, order: 2
7 => id:7, title: Seventh, order: 0
```

What I want is to sort these items this way:

```
1 => id:1, title: Hey, order: 1
4 => id:4, title: Forth, order: 2
6 => id:6, title: Sixth, order: 2
2 => id:2, title: Second, order: 3
3 => id:3, title: Third, order: 6
5 => id:5, title: Fifth, order: 0
7 => id:7, title: Seventh, order: 0
```

As you can see, what I want, is to order items by "order" field, but the items which their order is 0, I want them to go in the last of the list. Is there some SQL commands to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Please tag single RDBMS which you are using.

Comment: Calling a column "order" is not really a good choice, as `order` is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic Yep sorry to do so, I just thought I will get my answer sooner if I tag two databases! Thanks to mention.

Comment: @trincot It was just example wise bro, but good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `order by` the `ordering` column with zeros last.  A generic way is:

```
order by (case when ordering = 0 then 2 else 1 end), ordering
```

However, you have tagged two databases.  In MySQL, I would suggest:

order by (ordering <> 0) desc, ordering

or in Postgres:

```
order by nullif(ordering, 0) nulls last
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort by the boolean expression `"order" = 0` first and you will get `0`s last:

```
order by ("order" = 0), "order"
```

This will work in Postgresql.

In MySql you can do similarly:

```
order by (`order` = 0), `order`
```

Comment: No need to cast, you can order by Boolean directly.